# Xdebug run time is different from PHP run time at WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, debian, xdebug

Our WordPress theme working so slow on Apache, Debian Server.
(This can be occurs from File Permissions and/or WordPress and/or MariaDB)
We are trying to find the problem via Xdebug

The problem is according to the Xdebug everything is **all right**. :)
**However it is not.**

When we simply check process runtime as follow it took 3.062 **mseconds.**

```
$then = microtime();
myFunc();
$now = microtime();

echo sprintf("Elapsed:  %f", $now-$then);
```

However Xdebug shows it only took **482 mseconds.**

Why this difference occurs ? What causes this?
We tried Debug Bar plugin etc. Nothing helped us.
What is best way to find What is Slowing Down?

We are using WordPress with Xdebug on following environment

- WordPress 5.6.2
- MySQL Distrib 10.3.27-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
- Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- ISPConfig 3
- Apache/2.4.38 (Debian)
- PHP 7.3.27-1~deb10u1
- Zend Engine v3.3.27

  - with Zend OPcache v7.3.27-1~deb10u1

Our Xdebug config as follow:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=1
xdebug.profiler_output_name = "cachegrind.out.%u-%H-%R.txt"
xdebug.var_display_max_depth=10
xdebug.output_dir = /tmp
xdebug.log=10
xdebug.mode=develop,trace
```

Comment: I'd suggest disable XDebug at server and measure raw PHP again. Keep in mind it slows down execution time by itself.

Comment: @biesior some functions takes to much time. Probably few of them belong to Wordpress Core. Are there easy way to check them also?